# Eclipse without update sites?

Tags: eclipse, configuration

I just downloaded the "Java" and the "Classic" version of Eclipse 3.7 Indigo and in both cases there are no default update sites like the one from Indigo itself. What could have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Classic Eclipse SDK (that includes PDE and JDT) comes with the update sites pre-populated.  But if you can't see them, you can add them:

- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
- http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7

Comment: that's really what normally happens. It's not the first time I install eclipse. But this time it was different and I really don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

try to start eclipse as administrator, this works for me. Then all update sites were available.
without administrator start, no sites or only the two i added manually.
Also fixes the problem: ‘Missing requirement: Shared profile

http://msmvps.com/blogs/rfennell/archive/2011/07/18/solution-to-missing-requirement-shared-profile-1-0-0-1308118925849-error-when-installation-tee-sp1-on-eclipse-indigo.aspx

Comment: This was the same problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are re-using an existing workspace. Try to switch workspace, and set a non-existing folder. In that case, default settings should kick in.

Comment: the whole system is totally fresh. I can't use any old settings. Not just eclipse. Also Windows is reinstalled the HDD is reformatted.